# VS compiling BizTalk project cannot write to output directory

Tags: compiler-construction, visual-studio-2005, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

Sometimes (but not all of the time) when I compile my BizTalk project from with VS 2005, I receive the error:

```
Could not write to output file 'e:\...\obj\Development\whatever.dll' The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

It's Visual Studio that's using it. I just close the IDE and re-open and it will work.

I have had this problem for a while now, I just live with it but it's becoming increasingly frustrating. Does anyone know what's causing this? It's not something specific to my project, it happens for all of my projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think there is a bug in VS 2005. This is on a project that references my whatever.dll. I needed to set copy local to true and it compiles ok. I can set back to false but it will eventually error again. Even though I want copy local to false as everything BizTalk must be in the GAC, setting it to true in my case causes no harm, so I just leave them like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bug in VS2005, that also exists in VS2008.

But in VS2010 (BizTalk 2010), it almost never occurs. You can still get this problem, if you reference a project in one solution, and have the same project referenced in another solution, and both VS2010 solutions running at the same time.

Comment: I've had it occur with VS2010 on a regular basis, so that bug is still around.